# Цвет линий окошка чата

Tags: html

Как изменить цвет линий окошка в чате?
Чат:

```
<iframe name="chatWindow" id="chatWindow" src="iframe.php" width="1265" height="400"> </iframe> 
<form action="iframe.php" method="post" id="form" target="chatWindow">
```

Сообщение:

```
<input name="message" type="text" size="75" maxleght="255"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="OK">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
<title>Чат</title>
<style type="text/css">
#chatWindow{
border-color: #f00/*верхний цвет*/ #0ff/*правый цвет*/ #0f0/*нижний цвет*/ #00f/*левый цвет*/;
border-style: dotted/*верхняя граница точками*/ dashed/*п.г. штрихами*/ solid/*н.г. сплошная*/ double/*л.г. двойная*/;
border-width: 1px/*в.г*/ 2px/*п.г*/ 4px/*н.г*/ 3px/*л.г*/;
}
</style>
</head>
```